# Cascading combobox's from database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two combo boxes:

ComboBox1 - shows names from my database, works as intended

ComboBox2 - should show ages associated with that name from Combobox1, 
Additionally, I have a textbox that should show the name of the Son associated with the ComboxBox1 (Name) and ComboxBox2 (Age)

MySQL DataSet:

```
Name | Age | Son's Name
mark | 23  | john
mark | 22  | dell
mark | 30  | jack
joe  | 20  | joel
joe  | 22  | jason
```

For example, when I open comboxBox1 and chose "Mark", ComboBox2 should show me ages [23,22,30]. then when I select an age (lets say 22), the textbox should show "dell"

[image: Image of Application]

```
void Fillcombo() {
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    string Query = " select * from  database.check WHERE fathername  IS NOT NULL ;";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string sname = myReader.GetString("fathername");
            comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);
        }
    }
}

///// and i dont know what to write in combobox1 and combobox2 //////

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ztsmQ.jpg

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you've got so far, the community should be able to help you tweak it / fix it.

Comment: void Fillcombo() {
            string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
            string Query = " select * from  database.check WHERE patientname  IS NOT NULL ;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {

Comment: conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string sname = myReader.GetString("patientname");
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);
              
                    
                }

Comment: ///// and i dont know what to right in combobox1 and combobox2 //////
                   
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
    }


private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
    }

Comment: Please use the edit function under your original post. Code in Comments is almost illegible.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional code, I've got pseudo code to help you:

```
FatherComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(FatherComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

private void FatherComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

    string FathersName = (string) combo.SelectedValue;

    //Code to populate childrens ages in ages combo box
}

AgesComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(AgesComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

private void AgesComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

    string Age = (string) ComboBox.SelectedValue;

    //Code to select from database where age and fathers name == values given
    textbox.Text = queryResults
}
```